# DDL Indy forçando requisições em TLS 1.2

Tags: delphi, http-request, indy-10, tls

Estou tentando refatorar o código o código da DLL Gerencianet Pagamentos para que a DLL faça requisições somente pelo protocolo TLS 1.2. Referencia: [uGerenciaNetIndy.pas](https://github.com/gerencianet/gn-api-sdk-delphi/blob/master/src/dll-src/uGerenciaNetIndy.pas)

Estou compilando a DLL através do Delphi Embarcadeiro 10.1 update 2 Berlin com a Indy atualizada na versão 10.

Pesquisando pela net, pude notar que quando a DLL não consegue se comunicar pelo protocolo mais recente, ele volta para o mais antigo, neste caso 1.0, está certo isso?

Também pude notar a existência de DLLs para o windows atualizadas que dão suporte ao protocolo (libeay32, ssleay32), vi em um link do próprio forum: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809971/using-indy-10-idhttp-with-tls-1-2)

Eu devo pensar em usar um componente diferente e alterar a codificação, ou devo buscar considerar que a falha se faz pela ausência das DLL's? Confesso que tenho muitas dúvidas sobre o uso do Indy com o Delphi.

Ficaria agradecido se alguém puder auxiliar-me com um norte para esta questão.

Comment: Você esta setando a propriedade `IOHandler` do componente?

Comment: Prezado @JuniorMoreira, foi isso mesmo. Setei a propriedade do IOHandler e baixei as DLLs atualizadas do OPENSSL:

Result.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(Result.IOHandler).SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];

Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado ;)

Comment: Se o endpoint for um https não adianta apenas setar as propriedades e adicionar as DLL. É preciso informar para o componente qual o componente responsável pelo gerenciamento do SSL.
Necessário informar a propriedade `IOHandler` do `TIdHTTP`